# Formatting the input file in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am using pig for data analytic.So i want to format my input file:

```
column1a,column2a,column3a
column1b,column2b,column3b
column1c,column2c,column3c
column1d,column2d,column3d
```

and I want to generate this input as output:

```
column1a|column2a|column3a
column1b|column2b|column3b
column1c|column2c|column3c
column1d|column2d|column3d
```

how to generate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
a = LOAD '<path>' using PigStorage(',') as (f1,f2,f3)
b = FOREACH a GENERATE CONCAT(f1,'|',f2,'|',f3);
dump b;
```